# How to not affect strings when using a case convert shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I use Oracle SQL Developer to run queries. i wish the "Convert to lowercase" shortcut didn't affect text within the 'apostrophes'.

Notepad++ is much more easy on the eyes, so the query is written there and then copy-pasted into Oracle. I mapped all the shortcuts I used to use in Oracle to N++, but the strings are now also being converted to lower case.

Is there any way to stop this?

Example:

```sql
CASE
WHEN table.attribute = 'CaseSensitiveStringValue'
  THEN 'OutcomeValue'
  ELSE 'OTHERValue'
END AS CASEName
```

When converted to all lowercase is SQL Developer will look like this:

```sql
case
when table.attribute = 'CaseSensitiveStringValue'
  then 'OutcomeValue'
  else 'OTHERValue'
end as casename
```

Notice that the strings where not affected by the conversion. In Notepad++ the result of the convert-to-lowercase is as follows:

```sql
case
when table.attribute = 'casesensitivestringvalue'
  then 'outcomevalue'
  else 'othervalue'
end as casename
```

Notice that all text, including strings is now lowercase. This would break the code if the value is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Find & Replace feature in Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `'[^']+'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\w+`
- Replace with: `\L$0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
'[^']+'         # NOt a single quote between 2 single quote (i.e. strings we don't want to convert)
(*SKIP)         # skip this string
(*FAIL)         # fail to match
|               # OR
\w+             # 1 or more word character
```

**Replacement:**

```
\L$0        # lowercase the whole match (i.e. the string NOT between quotes)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
case
when table.attribute = 'CaseSensitiveStringValue'
  then 'OutcomeValue'
  else 'OTHERValue'
end as casename
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation!

Comment: @Panatella: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)